# Trying to print ASCII characters 128 to 160, why does it stop at 157?

Tags: python, ascii

I'm new to Python and I'm learning coding/encoding, unicode, ascii and so on.
I would like to print ASCII characters according to their codes and using chr() function.

```
def table_ascii():
    "procédure imprimant une table des caractères ascii avec leur valeurs"
    i = 127
    while i < 258:
        print(f"{i} -> {chr(i)}")
        i += 1

table_ascii()
```

Unfortunately, the result is wrong. It stops at the code 157 :

```
127 ->  
128 ->  
129 ->  
130 ->  
131 ->  
132 ->  

133 ->  

134 ->  
135 ->  
136 ->  
137 ->      
138 ->  
139 ->  
140 ->  
142 ->  
143 ->  
144 ->  
146 ->  
147 ->  
148 ->  
149 ->  
150 ->  
151 ->  
152 ->  
154 ->  
        155 ->  

157 ->
```

I understand these codes return blank but why do they stop the process?

Setup:

- Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
  [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
- Using VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1

When I run this code in Visual Studio Code, the script produces output through 256. But in my console (Linux Mate), it blocks. That's difficult to understand for me...

Comment: The premise of your task is flawed. ASCII only defines characters for the integer vallues 0-127. _There are no ASCII characters corresponding to the integers 128-160_. Interpreting 128-160 as characters strictly requires the use of an encoding other than ASCII (though possibly a superset of ASCII).

Comment: `chr` returns Unicode strings, and there are no (printable) characters defined for code points 127 through 159 for historical reasons.

Comment: Running this code produces output through 257 for me

Comment: You can see what the unicode characters look like in this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement) from 160 to 255. The code above outputs these characters to the console running from both Windows and Linux. Are you running code from Python interpreter interactively or have a .py file and running the script?

Comment: @Brian https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: I observed that when I run this code in Visual studio code, the script produces output through 256. But in my console (Linux mate), it blocks. That's difficult to understand for me...

Comment: On a separate note, since you’re learning, instead of incrementing `i` manually you can loop over a range, like `for i in range(0, 128)`.

Comment: `'latin1'` is very similar to ASCII and covers the entire range of codes from 0x00–0xFF.

Comment: I confirm the same effect on my machine (Ubuntu 20.4, python 3.9): running the code inside ipython or as a script displaying in the terminal, it stops at 157.

Comment: If you start counter variable at 160 does it print characters up to 257 ?

Comment: Yep. The only characters that create problem are 157, 158 and 159.

Comment: @nonDucor What happens when you go backwards, from 257 to 127?

Comment: Your terminal may be treating 158 as the start of a "private message" and not displaying anything. I'm not sure, but I think that backspace would terminate that message. You could add `if i == 159: print("\b")` to see if more stuff shows up.

Comment: @KellyBundy, it stops in 159.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. Its a legitimate issue when outputting to a console that implements escape codes.

Comment: @tdelaney it's reopened now

Comment: ASCII codes between `0x80` and `0xFF` are referred to as an "**Extended ASCII table**". (See [here](https://www.ascii-code.com/).) However, the codes within that extended table varies in the range `0x80-0x9F`, depending on the PC/terminal character set *encoding* is used, **and** what *fonts* have been installed to support those codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, ASCII only goes up to 127 (0x7F). `chr()` actually returns the *Unicode* character.

I think the problem is that when U+9D (157) *Operating System Command (OSC)* is printed, your terminal starts a control string and waits for a String Terminator like U+9C *String Terminator*, U+1B *Escape* followed by U+5C backslash, or U+7 *BEL*. Since none of those sequences are ever printed later, the terminal stops showing the output. For more info, see [ANSI escape code § Fe Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) and [C1 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_controls) on Wikipedia.

Unicode characters U+80 (128) to U+9F (159) are control characters, meaning they're not generally printable, so you were never going to get sensible output in the first place.

Comment: Excellent! I changed the print line to `print(f"{i} -> {chr(i)}{chr(0x9c)}")` to always ensure it is terminated and it worked

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments the characters between 128 and 160 are something of a no-man's land. They are not defined in the Unicode spec but they may have special meaning for various displays. That's the reason why Unicode doesn't touch them - too many variable uses in play.

A terminal such as a Linux xterm accepts control codes to do things like display text in color. Looking at [Xterm Control Sequences](https://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html) we see

```
Privacy Message (PM is 0x9e)
```

That's 158 decimal and its one of xterms 8-bit control characters. This starts a "private message" that continues until a defined string terminator character is seen. xterm doesn't implement "private message" and it looks from your output that it simply ignores the remaining output as being part of that message.

This is a VT100 type thing. Some terminals may implement some actions. Others may have a character mapped to that octet. You won't find any consistent implementation.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C0_and_C1_control_codes#/Unicode:

### in unicode

Unicode sets aside 65 code points in the general category Cc (control) for **compatibility** with ISO/IEC 2022. These are:

1. U+0000 – U+001F (C0 controls) and U+007F (delete),   assigned to the Basic Latin block
2. U+0080 – U+009F (C1 controls), assigned to the Latin-1 Supplement block.

Unicode only specifies semantics for:

1. U+0009 – U+000D,  U+001C – U+001F
2. U+0085    (NEL, Next Line. Equivalent to CR+LF.
   Used to mark end-of-line on some IBM mainframes.)

The rest of the control codes are **transparent to Unicode**,
and their meanings are left to higher-level protocols.

In the general category Cf (format),  there are other **format effector** characters, e.g.:

1. the zero-width joiner
2. non-joiner (controlling ligature)